# DirectX -- Render a quad to a WicBitmapRenderTarget (SharpDX)

Tags: bitmap, directx, direct3d, direct2d, wic

I'm trying to use Direct3D11 to perform some image warping really fast as per [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350000/mapping-corners-to-arbitrary-positions-using-direct2d/11362129) but can't seem to get everything working together.

Things are failing when I try to read the DXGI Surface into a Direct2D bitmap.

```
var renderSurface = renderTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Surface>();
var props = new BitmapProperties
                {
                    PixelFormat = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(
                        Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                        AlphaMode.Premultiplied
                    )
                };

// This throws "No such interface supported"
var direct2DBitmap = 
    new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(_bitmapRenderTarget, renderSurface, props);
```

I've also tried to read the surface directly using the `Map` method, but that fails before I even attempt to do anything with the data:

```
var renderSurface = renderTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Surface>();
// This throws "The parameter is incorrect."
renderSurface.Map(MapFlags.Read);
```

More complete code is below. Also if there's anything in here that's extraneous to this job... I'm all ears. I'm not really a 3D person, just trying to solve a very specific problem that doesn't have an easy Direct2D solution.

```
public void AddImage(BitmapSource bitmapSource, SharpDX.Vector2[] abcd)
{
    Device device;
    Texture2D renderTexture = null;
    device = new Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);
    renderTexture = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription
    {
        Width = _size.Width,
        Height = _size.Height,
        Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
        MipLevels = 1,
        ArraySize = 1,
        SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    });
    var renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, renderTexture);

    //
    // Load the input bitmap as a texture
    //
    var texture = CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(device, bitmapSource);
    var textureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture);
    var sampler = new SamplerState(device, new SamplerStateDescription()
    {
        Filter = Filter.MinMagMipLinear,
        AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
        AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
        AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
        BorderColor = Color.Black,
        ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Never,
        MaximumAnisotropy = 16,
        MipLodBias = 0,
        MinimumLod = 0,
        MaximumLod = 16,
    });

    //
    // Setup the scene
    // These shaders are from the MiniCubeTexture sample for SharpDX
    //
    var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCubeTexture.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0");
    var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);
    var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCubeTexture.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0");
    var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

    var layout = new InputLayout(device, ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode), new[] {
        new InputElement("POSITION", 0, SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
    new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32G32_Float, 16, 0),
    });

    var vertices = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[] {
    // 3D coordinates              UV Texture coordinates
        abcd[0].X, abcd[0].Y,  0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, // Front
        abcd[1].X, abcd[1].Y,  0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,
        abcd[2].X, abcd[2].Y,  0.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
        abcd[3].X, abcd[3].Y,  0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
    });

    var contantBuffer = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(device, Utilities.SizeOf<Matrix>(), ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);

    var context = device.ImmediateContext;
    context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
    context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
    context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertices, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector2>(), 0));
    context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, contantBuffer);
    context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
    context.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, _size.Width, _size.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);
    context.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, sampler);
    context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);
    context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(renderView);

    //
    // Render 3D
    //          
    context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Colors.Transparent);
    var worldViewProj = Matrix.Identity;// Matrix.Translation (_size.Width, _size.Height / 2, 0) * Matrix.Scaling (_size.Width / 2, _size.Height / 2, 1);
    context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, contantBuffer);
    context.Draw(4, 0);

    //
    // Composite
    //

    //Create a render target

    var renderSurface = renderTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Surface>();
    var props = new BitmapProperties
                    {
                        PixelFormat = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,AlphaMode.Premultiplied)
                    };

    var direct2DBitmap = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(_bitmapRenderTarget, renderSurface, props);

    _wicRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
    _wicRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(direct2DBitmap, 1.0f, SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
    _wicRenderTarget.EndDraw();

    direct2DBitmap.Dispose();
}

private static SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    // Allocate DataStream to receive the WIC image pixels
    int stride = bitmapSource.Size.Width * 4;
    using (var buffer = new SharpDX.DataStream(bitmapSource.Size.Height * stride, true, true))
    {
        // Copy the content of the WIC to the buffer
        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
        return new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Width = bitmapSource.Size.Width,
            Height = bitmapSource.Size.Height,
            ArraySize = 1,
            BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Immutable,
            CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
            Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            MipLevels = 1,
            OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        }, new SharpDX.DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer, stride));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [CreateSharedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a ID2D1Bitmap and use it in your Direct2D scene. From the [SharpDX sources](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/Bitmap.cs?r=16afffae5bf5b7879abbb4ce6873122f576e0748#85), it looks like there are multiple overloaded constructors for Bitmap that call CreateSharedBitmap.

Also check out the documentation on interop between Direct2D and Direct3D via DXGI [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#interoperability_through_dxgi).

**EDIT:** After some searching, [it looks like](http://sharpdx.org/forum/5-api-usage/164-d3d11-d2d1-direct3d-and-2d-interop) the method I suggested above is [not supported on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485265/cant-create-direct2d-dxgi-surface) (only on Windows 8).

A workaround is [here](http://www.aaronblog.us/?p=36), though.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the constructor I'm calling is one that calls CreateSharedBitmap so something else must be afoot.

Comment: Argh. The sheer amount of incantations needed to work with DX continues to amaze me.

Comment: :) A pure Direct3D experience might have been less frustrating, sorry for the bad news.